# Sqoop error while importing

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am new to sqoop and trying ti import a table in MYSQL table widgets table from the hadoopguide Database.

I am using Hadoop version 0.20.

and my Sqoop is sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-0.20

I am Running the command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopguide --table widgets -m 1
```

This is error log I am getting

```
Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
13/09/25 15:29:41 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming     resultset.
13/09/25 15:29:41 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
13/09/25 15:29:41 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM     `widgets` AS t LIMIT 1
13/09/25 15:29:41 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `widgets` AS t LIMIT 1
13/09/25 15:29:41 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop
13/09/25 15:29:41 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Found hadoop core jar at: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar
Note: /tmp/sqoop-ubuntu/compile/348861f092b25aac3fae4089da9abdf0/widgets.java uses or     overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
13/09/25 15:29:42 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-    ubuntu/compile/348861f092b25aac3fae4089da9abdf0/widgets.jar
13/09/25 15:29:42 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
13/09/25 15:29:42 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --    direct
13/09/25 15:29:42 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast     path.
13/09/25 15:29:42 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to     convertToNull (mysql)
13/09/25 15:29:42 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of widgets
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getCredentials()Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/Credentials;
    at     org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getPassword(DBConfiguration.java:304)
    at     org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:272)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:187)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:239)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:600)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:413)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Can anyone have any idea about it.

Comment: Can you list the tables with `sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopguide`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed hive, hcatalog is installed with it. Now set the `HCAT_HOME` in your `.bashrc` as below

```
cd ~
gedit .bashrc
   export HCAT_HOME=${HIVE_HOME}/hcatalog/
   export PATH=$HCAT_HOME/bin:$PATH

source .bashrc //to refresh the .bashrc file
```

otherwise install hcatalog saperately and set home path.

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop release 0.20 is very old release that is lacking a lot of features. One feature that Sqoop requires is a security additions that were added in 1.x. As a result Sqoop won't work on bare 0.20, at least CDH3u1 or Hadoop 1.x is required. I would strongly suggest to upgrade your Hadoop cluster.